# Running a script in Docker container by accepting -e parameter

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a very simple script called as myscript.sh

```
echo "this is test " > /tmp/myfile.txt
echo $TEST >> /tmp/myfile.txt
```

I have stored this script in my disk which i plan to pass it to the container as a volume like this below

```
docker run -d --name test \
   -v /home/docker/test/myscript.sh:/tmp/myscript.sh \
   -e TESTING=just-a-test \
   test
```

The Dockerfile looks like this below

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD ["bash", "/tmp/myscript.sh"]
```

So the thought process is to get this script executed and get the result as a file myfile.txt which would contain the -e  passed.

Instead i am getting

> docker@boot2docker:~/test$ docker exec -it test /bin/bash Error
>   response from daemon: Container test is not running

Which means that this simplest program did not execute as a container.
I Could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use the entrypoint instead of cmd.
I did some research and i came up with the solution that looks like this

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "<script>"]
```

To run the script just use
docker run -d --name  [--privileged] -p : \
        - v /script.sh:/tmp/script.sh \

where -v <> : YOU CAN ALSO USE THE WGET TO GET THE SCRIPT LIKE MOST PEOPLE AND EXECUTE AT RUNTIME.

Appreciate all the people who tried to solve the query

Answer (score 1):

The container ran, executed the script, then exited. A container only runs as long as its main process. When that stops, the container stops.

A simpler test would be to change your test script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $TEST
```

I would change your Dockerfile to copy the file in and remove the "bash" part of the CMD instruction:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY myscript.sh /myscript.sh
CMD /myscript.sh
```

Now rebuild and run:

```
$ docker build -t test .
...
$ docker run -e TEST=VAL test 
...
```

The container should echo the value of the test variable and exit. (I haven't tested any of this, so apologies for any mistakes).

Comment: Please don't apologies, i really appreciate you coming forward to help me. Thank you for that.  Copying the script won't help because if you see i have overwrote the volume, it should directly take from it..     What i tried today was to use the entry point to put in the script and have jenkins in it running so that the container is up and I am able to see the file..

Comment: I only copied the script because it's a lot simpler than using a volume and I don't really understand why you would use a volume for this.

Comment: This is just a test. Generally if you see, people would wget their script at runtime using git etc and then execute it in entrypoint.. I did not want to put anything in git as of now so for simple testing i wanted to make my script available to the container. Hence to do this I used volumes

Comment: OK. I still don't understand the use case, but it should work just the same with a volume.